# Intranet URL to an Excel does not open in Chrome when serve from external site

Tags: sharepoint-server, url, office, chrome, external

I don't use SharePoint so I'm hoping the below description is sufficient. Sorry if it's a bit vague.

So we have a website that allows the client to enter and save a bunch a URLs. The website would create a simple anchor for them to click on e.g. `<a href="http://servername/thingy/bob/blah.xlsx" target="_blank">Like this</a>`. The user is putting links to their **internal SharePoint** and is complaining that when they use **chrome** and the link is to an **excel** or a **docx** file, it would not open the file but if the link is to a PDF then it would open the file. They also said that if they inspect the html and click on the href link it would open the file. When they "Open in a new Window" the URL is intact but it still does not open the file (excel in this case). According to the user, the file opens when they use Microsoft Edge (a prompt appear and they click 'Open').

Is there any settings on SharePoint that would prevent an intranet URL link from an external site on Chrome, opening Office related files when the user clicks on it? Does this ring any bells?